# How can I create a query with conditional?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to put a conditional in an array.

I want

```
   if policy.date_ini >= insurance.initial_date do
      sum of all net_ensurance where date_ini >= initial_date
   end
```

Tables

```
   |policies|
     |id|   |date_ini|  |num_policy|
      1      2013-02-30      1234

   |insurances|
     |id|  |policy_id|   |initial_date|   |net_ensurance|
      1       1            2013-03-30         1000
      2       1            2013-02-30         2000 
      3       1            2012-12-05         5000
```

And I should have

```
      |num_policy|  |sum_net_ensurance|
        1234                 3000
```

NOTE:
My relation in database is this:

```
 class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :insurances
 end

 class Insurance < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :policy
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're a little confused.  You are asking for the sum of net_esureance where policy date is >= initial date.

First, `2013-02-30` isn't a valid date.  Feb only has 28 days.

EDIT:  Are you storing this as a varchar column? That's a really bad idea.

So, I replaced it with `2013-02-28`.

Next, do you really mean where policy date is >= than initial date?  If so, that's true for every row, so you'll get back `7000.`

```
SELECT num_policy,
sum(CASE WHEN p.date_ini >= i.initial_date
THEN ( net_ensurance) ELSE 0 END) FROM policies p
INNER JOIN insurances i ON p.id = i.policy_id
```

result:

```
NUM_POLICY  SUM_NET_ESURANCE
1234        7000

enter code here
```

If you meant the other way around, you'll get the 3000 you are expecting:

```
SELECT num_policy,
sum(CASE WHEN  i.initial_date >= p.date_ini
THEN ( net_ensurance) ELSE 0 END) FROM policies p
INNER JOIN insurances i ON p.id = i.policy_id
```

result:

```
NUM_POLICY  SUM_NET_ESURANCE
1234        3000
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ee7e/5)

Comment: I'm guilty i forgot about febraury :) but the idea was like that

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT num_policy,CASE WHEN policy.date_ini >= insurance.initial_date
THEN SUM( net_ensurance) ELSE 0 END FROM policies p
INNER JOIN insurances i ON p.id = i.policy_id
```

Comment: i used your code and i got => Unknown column 'policy.date_ini' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    p.id AS num_policy,
    SUM(i.net_ensurance) AS net_ensurance
FROM policies p
INNER JOIN insurances i ON p.id = i.policy_id AND p.date_ini >= i.initial_date
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: I used your code and i got :" #1054 - Unknown column 'i.net_ensurance' in 'field list"